# Raise message dialog in TortoiseHg UI

Tags: user-interface, hook, tortoisehg

I've written a commit hook that is working just fine from the command line:

**example.py**

```
def saysomething(ui, repo, **kwargs):
    ui.status('today is 26-May')
```

I've configured my repository's .hg\hgrc file to include:

```
[hooks]
commit = python:/path/to/example.py:saysomething
```

And when I commit from the command line, I get the output "today is 26-May", as expected.

But I cannot convince the TortoiseHg GUI to display the message on committing.  Am I using the wrong syntax in my python script?  Do I need to add the hook in some configuration file other than the repository's hgrc? I also tried adding the hook to the global .hgrc file, but this didn't help, and it would have been a bad solution to my problem anyhow.

I've looked through [the HG guide on writing hooks](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Hook), [the guide on writing extensions](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/WritingExtensions), and the TortoiseHg guide, and I don't see an explanation anywhere on how to do this.

Using TortoiseHg 2.0.4, including Mercurial 1.8, on Windows XP.

Comment: The text should appear in TortoiseHg console window.